# Sorting search results with mongoid-elasticsearch gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, mongoid

I am trying to implement sorting into my search. I am searching with use of the gem `mongoid-elasticsearch`. This is my model configuration:

```
class ActivityLog
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Elasticsearch
  elasticsearch!(
    {
      wrapper: :load,
      sort: [
        { created_at: "desc" }
      ]
    }
  )

  field :type, type: String
end
```

This configuration does not raise any errors, but it does not either seem like it has any effect, because search results are listed randomly.

I think I am implementing the configuration in accordance to the documentation:

[Check mongoid-elasticsearch documentation here](https://github.com/rs-pro/mongoid-elasticsearch#advanced)

[Check elasticsearch documentation here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html)

My search query btw is:

```
ActivityLog.es.search(params[:query], page: params[:page]).results.paginate(per_page: 5, page: params[:page])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove Array wrapper:

```
elasticsearch!(
  {
    wrapper: :load,
    sort: { created_at: "desc" }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The same way you would do it in Elasticsearch itself

```
ActivityLog.es.search({
  body: {
    query: {
      query_string: {
        query: params[:search]
      }
    },
    sort: [
        {created_at: {order: "asc"}},
    ]
  })
```